# How to install apk without rebuilding whole project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, adb

Building apk for large project take much time to process all Gradle task.

I have try this but it clean and build

```
$ gradle installDebug
```

How to write separate gradle task and add to project Gradle run configuration. 

So that by simply excuting gradle task it install existing build debug apk or release apk or any other build type without rebuidling it.
 
It will save deployment time of apk in multiple devices

Comment: You can write a task that runs bash/sh code to call "adb install -r <path to apk>"

Comment: @PedroOliveira How to do that in custom gradle task in project level build.gradle file?

Comment: Try this @Qamar https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-execute-shell-command-source-or-dot-doesnt-work-with-exec/7271/10

Comment: It would be something like `task installApk(type: Exec) { task ->
    executable "adb"
    args "install","-r", "${root}/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk"
}` but this doesn't work for me

Comment: Have you tried a hardcoded path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this can help you: I created a new shell file `install_apk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage
#   run ./install_apk          # to install debug apk
#   run ./install_apk release  # to install release apk

if [ $1 == "release" ]; then
    adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk
    echo "install release apk"
else
    echo "install debug apk"
    adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, Can we wrap this in gradle script like `task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can update android studio to version > 2.0 which has instant run as a built in feature

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

here some more details , cheers

Comment: instant run works once you run app. I need to add new phone and install apk using gradle task like `task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`

Comment: sure, sorry, i might have misunderstand your question. good luck